# How do I compare form inputs with database values in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a form to input a user id and I want compare this id with database values (usrId).

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserInfo

class NameForm(forms.Form):
  your_id = forms.CharField(label='Your id', max_length=100)
  def clean(self):
     cleaned_data = super(NameForm, self).clean()
     your_id = cleaned_data.get("your_id")
     p = UserInfo.objects.all()
     if your_id:
        for i in p:
           if i.usrId not in your_id:
              raise forms.ValidationError(
                   "User not exist."
                  )
```

When I do this nothing happens and I get `User not exist.` for any value.

**models.py**

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   usrId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   poste = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   date1 = models.DateTimeField('date of recruitment')
   def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
      return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required

        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return generate_pdf(request, Type_id)

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
        form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'rh/detail.html', {'form': form, 'type_id': Type_id})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the user id that you are trying to match does indeed exists (log that id and query the database manually to make sure). Your code should be changed as follows:

```
try:
    p = UserInfo.objects.get(id=your_id)
except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
    raise forms.ValidationError("User not exist.")
```

This code is shorter and more efficient (you are not fetching all the user objects as in the current version)